# Appium and Robot Framework: Element locator with prefix not supported

Tags: appium, robotframework

My attempt to click a skip button on a mobile app.

> Error: ValueError: Element locator with prefix
>   'android.widget.textview[@resource- id' is not supported

```
 AppiumLibrary.Click Element  android.widget.TextView[@resource-id='sg.onemap.android.onemap2:id/tv_skip']
```

Tried another way but got another error message

> InvalidSelectorException: Message: Locator Strategy 'css selector' is
>   not supported for this session

```
Click Element  id='sg.onemap.android.onemap2:id/tv_skip'
```

Also, it would be good if anyone have any good examples on how to write appium actions to perform on mobile applications using robot framework.

Comment: your id element looks to have a space in between resource- id is that meant to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the RF Appium KW docs here [AppiumLibrary](https://serhatbolsu.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/AppiumLibrary.html) you can see an example of referencing an id.

```
Click Element | id=my_element
```

id not even required.